# Why Gatsby Browser Error occur when run create react app?

Tags: create-react-app, gatsby

I want use gatsby-image in a create react application and when i install gatsby in react and after execute i got this error

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/gatsby-browser-entry.js
SyntaxError: 
/node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/gatsby-browser-entry.js: Unexpected 
token (25:4)


return (
 <React.Fragment>
    ^
     {finalData && render(finalData)}
     {!finalData && <div>Loading (StaticQuery)</div>}
   </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Could you please expand with more details about your environment and the commands you used to install? It seems to me that probably some dependencies might be missing, but I can't tell.

Comment: Normally i created react app using create-react-app and than install all gatsby dependencies in react app using 
"gatsby": "^2.15.28",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.2.23",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.20",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.0.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.2.27",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.28",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.2.19",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1"

and than when i use import { graphql } from "gatsby" in app.js
it will throw error

Comment: I want to use lazy loading images ( first blur effect and than full image, same as website of medium ), gatsby provide that feature so i'm trying to use gatsby in react,
When i install gatsby seperatly ( new folder) according to docs of gatsby than its working same as https://using-gatsby-image.gatsbyjs.org/ (lazy loading image )
But when i try to install in our react app than it throw error

Comment: Its possible to use gatsby in react app ?

Comment: You should probably use gatsby *instead of* create-react-app.

Comment: I asked you about the specific commands you ran, to try to understand what you did. It's true that official docs tend to focus on starting a new site built from scratch.

Comment: I'm running into the same error when trying to build a component library I will use in Gatsby. The command the produces it for me is `rollup -c`.